# How to extract certain words from character vector in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

How to extract certain words from a character vector in MATLAB?
I am struggling to work that out. I would like to obtain only the city names from this character vector:

```
myText = 'Vienna 2.7  Gallen  3.8  Zurich 0.9    Lugano 2.8   Rome 12.1   Paris 9.2'
```

Comment: Can a several-word name like "San Francisco" or "Den Haag" be in that string?

Comment: yes that could be possible!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This handles **several-word** names (*San Francisco*, *Newcastle upon Tyne*), including **dashes** (*Carmel-by-the-Sea*), **apostrophes** (*L'Aquila*) or **dots** followd by a space (*St. Gallen*). It assumes that the names are separated by any character other than letters, dash, space or apostrophe, and that the numbers never end in a dot:

```
result = strtrim(regexp(myText, '([a-zA-Z\- '']|\. )+', 'match'));
```

Example:

```
>> myText = 'San Francisco 2.7  Newcastle upon Tyne  3.8  Carmel-by-the-sea 0.9    L''Aquila 2.8  St. Gallen';
>> result = strtrim(regexp(myText, '([a-zA-Z\- '']|\. )+', 'match'))  
result =
  1×5 cell array
    {'San Francisco'}    {'Newcastle upon Tyne'}    {'Carmel-by-the-sea'}    {'L'Aquila'}    {'St. Gallen'}
```

Comment: You could get rid of strtrim with a slightly [more complex pattern](https://regex101.com/r/GBOFsg/1)

Comment: @UnbearableLightness I know it can be done... but I wanted to keep the regexp simple. Maybe post that as a separate answer?

Comment: @UnbearableLightness thanks a lot, thats exactly what I was looking for. I also have cities like "St. Gallen", where the strtrim doesn't work.

Comment: Well, in that case you need to add the `.` to the character set `(?:[A-Z][a-z]*)(?:[' -.]+[A-Za-z]+)*`

Comment: @UnbearableLightness I think it should be `\.` Anyway, the problem then is that the dots in the numbers would also be incorrectly identifed as city names. Mike, can we ensure that the dot in the city name is always followed by a space? I've edited my answer based on that

Comment: @LuisMendo You don't need to escape the `.` in a character class

Comment: @UnbearableLightness Ah, thanks. With my approach it does seem to be necessary

Answer (score 5):

You can break the string into a vector of strings using this:

```
cities = split(myText);
```

Then index just the names:

```
cities = cities(1:2:end);
```

Comment: Was not aware of the split function. Nice +1

Answer (score 2):

```
function out = extractName ( myText ) 
listOfWords = regexp(myText, '(([a-z_A-Z])+\s)' ,'match'  )
deleteLast = @(x) x(1:end-1);
out = cellfun(deleteLast , listOfWords ,'Uni', 0 ) ;
```

Then you can run it simply:

```
listOfNames = extractName(myText);
```

Comment: I couldn't figure out the ([a-z_A-Z])+ term, so thanks a lot!

Comment: Following code also works: `[match, ~] = regexp(myText, '[a-zA-Z]*', 'match', 'split');
`

Comment: Nice answer: possibly the best +1 from me (I missed twice a 'split', but I like your answer better, since it is more robust and coincise).

Comment: Why not `listOfWords = regexp(myText, '(([a-z_A-Z])+)' ,'match'  )` and avoid the `deleteLat` part? Is that required for some reason?

Comment: @LuisMendo: because I am not that good with regular expressions, I guess.; so I used \s to split the words, but your solution makes it unnecessary; so possibly my preferred solution is 

extractName = @(myText) regexp(myText, '(([a-z_A-Z])+)' ,'match' ); +1 from me. P.S.: depending on the requirements a function may be not needed.